# Problems with innerHTML - not recognizing a class from css

Tags: javascript, css, innerhtml

I'm trying to display a pop up model (it's supposed to be a login form) using *innerHTML*, I have many *divs* with their respectives classes, but my first *div*'s class it's not being recognized for some reason.

Before i tried to do this pop up using this:

```js
document.querySelector('.caixa-entrar').style.display = "flex";
```

It worked but I had so many problems with closing those pop ups. My teacher suggested to use *innerHTML* because he said it was easier. At least the way he showed me was...

This is my body:

```html
<header id="menu"> 
    <button id="cadastrar" class="button-flex-son">Cadastrar</button>
    <button id="entrar" class="button-flex-son">Entrar</button>
</header>
<div></div>
```

caixa's CSS

```css
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
overflow: hidden;
```

conteudo's CSS

```css
height: 300px;
width: 500px;
background-color: #3E94D1;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px;
position: relative;
border-radius: 4px;
```

My JS script

```js
const caixa = document.querySelector('div')
document.getElementById('entrar').addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    caixa.innerHTML = 

    '<div class="caixa">' + 
        '<div class="conteudo">' + 
            '<div class="close">+</div>' +
                //Insira o coisa de imagem aqui depois, arrombado 
            '<form class="forms" action="">' + 
                '<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" class="inputao">' + 
                '<input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" class="inputao">' +
                '<button type="submit" class="butao">Entrar</button>' +
                '<button type="submit" id="cadastro-butao" class="butao">Cadastro</button>' +
            '</form>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>'
});
```

All of this work, but the first *div*'s class don't. it was supposed to make the pop up model appear in blue in the center of the page, and the rest of the background should change its color

Comment: how did you import the css, from seperate file? are sure no other css class with the same name `caixa`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to get all the form being build inside a JS function, because it'll slower your code. Your teacher tricked you into thinking that it'll be easier to hide a whole set of HTML code into JS and calling it over the `addEventListener` parameter.

You could just set the form position and styles over your body and hide it, then call it on the `onClick` event over the "Entrar" button, simple as that. I made a Snippet so you can see if that's what you're willing to happen, and also you can see the code and feel free to implement into your website, here you have it :

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("hiddenForm");

//Oh desgraça, isso aqui é só pra fechar o Modal mesmo quando clicar do lado de fora
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background-color: #333;
  filter: brightness(100%);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

button:hover {
  filter: brightness(50%);
}

.cancelbtn {
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  background-color: #500;
}

.container {
  padding: 30px;
}

span.pass {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 5% auto 15% auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 80%;
}

.close {
  position: inherit;
  float: right;
  top: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.animate {
  animation: animatezoom 0.3s
}

@keyframes animatezoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
    }
}
```

```html
<h2>Try me</h2>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('hiddenForm').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Entrar</button>

<div id="hiddenForm" class="modal">

  <form class="modal-content animate" action="#">
    <span onclick="document.getElementById('hiddenForm').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>

    <div class="container">
      <label for="uname"><b>E-mail</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" name="uname" required>

      <label for="psw"><b>Senha</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" name="pass" required>

      <button type="button">Entrar</button>
      <button type="button">Cadastro</button>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('hiddenForm').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      <span class="pass">Forgot your <a href="#">password?</a></span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```